# Bounding $\frac{\operatorname{Tr}WC}{\operatorname{Tr}WCW^T}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $C$ is a positive definite real-valued matrix and $W$ positive stable real-valued (all eigenvalues have positive real part). The following seems true [empirically](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/Published/forum-positive-stable-bound.nb), is it possible to show this rigorously?

$$\frac{2\operatorname{Tr}WC}{\operatorname{Tr}WCW^T}\ge\lambda_{\text{min}}((W+W^T)(WW^T)^{-1})$$

Here $\lambda_{\text{min}}(A)$ refers to the smallest eigenvalue

When $W$ is positive definite, the equation above simplifies to

$$\frac{\operatorname{Tr}WC}{\operatorname{Tr}WCW^T}\ge \lambda_{\text{min}}W^{-1}$$

Comment: In the general case can't the LHS be complex and so the inequality is not so well defined? Moreover the RHS looks symmetric and so should have real eigenvalues anyway so no need for taking the real part?

Comment: Good point about LHS, added restriction to real-valued entries. However RHS is not symmetric

Comment: Ahh true, my mistake. You could make the RHS symmetric as eigenvalues are invariant under cyclic permutations though. Not sure it makes the proof any easier.

Comment: ok, I think you are right, updated

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof for the statement where $W$ is positive definite. Hopefully this can help prove the more general statement although I don't see how to at the moment.

Consider the optimization
$$
\begin{aligned}
\min_C& \quad \frac{\mathrm{Tr}[W C]}{\mathrm{Tr}[W^2 C]} \\
\mathrm{s.t.}& \quad C \geq 0
\end{aligned}
$$
Notice that the objective function is invariant under rescaling of $C$. Therefore, for any feasible point we could always rescale $C$ so that $\mathrm{Tr}[W^2 C] = 1$ without changing the objective value. This implies that the optimization is equivalent to the following optimization
$$
\begin{aligned}
\min_C& \quad \mathrm{Tr}[W C] \\
\mathrm{s.t.}& \quad \mathrm{Tr}[W^2 C] = 1 \\
& \quad C \geq 0
\end{aligned}
$$
This is an semidefinite program it has a strictly feasible point (namely $C = W^{-2}/d$ where $d$ is the dimension) and hence its optimal value is equal to the optimal value of the dual problem
$$
\begin{aligned}
\max & \quad \mu \\
\mathrm{s.t.}& \quad W - \mu W^2  \geq 0
\end{aligned}
$$
But thinking about the spectral decomposition of $W$ this positive semidefinite constraint is just equivalent to $\lambda_i - \mu \lambda_i^2 \geq 0$ for all $i$ where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $W$. Rearranging we find
$$
\mu \geq \frac{1}{\lambda_i} \qquad \text{ for all $i$}
$$
and hence $\mu \geq \lambda_{\min}(W^{-1})$ from which we have the result
$$
\frac{\mathrm{Tr}[W C]}{\mathrm{Tr}[W^2 C]} \geq \lambda_{\min}(W^{-1})\,.
$$